# Oracle Query modification

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

ORACLE QUERY

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW inventory (
        "ARTICLENO ",
        "EAN",
        "NAME",
        "BRAND"
      ) AS
        SELECT
            m.ARTICLENO,
            m.EAN,
            m.NAME,
            p.BRAN
        FROM
            ITEM   m,
            P_ITEM p
        WHERE
            m.ean = p.ean OR m.ARTICLE=p.ARTICLE;
```

(problem is in m.article=p.article i want only single record when comare not all)

Table = ITEM: as m

| ARTICLENO | EAN | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | a |
| 2 | null | x |

VIEW = P_ITEM as p

| ARTICLENO | EAN | NAME | BRAND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | a | b1 |
| 2 | null | x | b2 |
| 2 | null | x | b2 |
| 2 | null | x | b2 |

VIEW = INV_ITEM as inv

| ARTICLENO | EAN | NAME | BRAND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | a | b1 |
| 2 | null | x | b2 |

VIEW = INV_ITEM

DESIRE RESULT:

| ARTICLENO | EAN | NAME | BRAND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | a | b1 |
| 2 | null | x | b2 |

BUT GETTING

| ARTICLENO | EAN | NAME | BRAND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | a | b1 |
| 2 | null | x | b2 |
| 2 | null | x | b2 |
| 2 | null | x | b2 |

When inserting data in ITEM table I want if Ean is not null then compare by Ean like m.EAN = p.EAN  and insert into inv_item

and if Ean is null then compare by article m.ARTICLE = p.ARTICLE but it should be distinct article.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? These are two different DBMS. Then, please edit your request and format your query so it gets readable. I.e. insert some line feeds and when your are done highlight the query and click the code button `{}`.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired output, because textual description is not clear

Comment: And the query will become more readable if you rewrite it with the explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of cross join with `where` clause. This also should provide you a way to join different tables on different conditions and avoid the issue you currently have in the `where`

Comment: What if there are non-unique article records in p_item?

Comment: I have edit the query and tables please check now

Answer (score 0):

There are some wrong column names (p.BRAN and p.ARTICLE), but it seems you just need to select DISTINCT records...

```
WITH
    item AS
        (
            Select 1 "ARTICLENO", 100 "EAN", 'a' "NAME" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2 "ARTICLENO", Null "EAN", 'x' "NAME" From Dual
        ),
    p_item AS
        (
            Select 1 "ARTICLENO", 100 "EAN", 'a' "NAME", 'b1' "BRAND" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2 "ARTICLENO", Null "EAN", 'x' "NAME", 'b2' "BRAND" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2 "ARTICLENO", Null "EAN", 'x' "NAME", 'b2' "BRAND" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2 "ARTICLENO", Null "EAN", 'x' "NAME", 'b2' "BRAND" From Dual 
        )

SELECT DISTINCT
    m.ARTICLENO,
    m.EAN,
    m.NAME,
    p.BRAND
FROM
    ITEM   m
INNER JOIN
    P_ITEM p ON(m.ean = p.ean OR m.ARTICLENO = p.ARTICLENO)
```